# Is there way to keep delimiter also in records , while reading them with Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-plugins

I want to override Hadoop's default record reader within my Java code. It reads records line-by-line by default. I changed it when it encounters ":", separates the records. However, while seprating the records, it also emits the delimiter. So for example, my records are:

```
> I go to school : He goes to school : we go to school
```

When records are read, it produces like:

```
I go to school
He goes to school
we go to school
```

However the delimiter - ":" is gone. Is there way to keep this delimiter in records? Because there may be some important informations in delimiters.

Comment: What kind of important information? Generally, the whole point of a delimiter is that it sits in-between the important information. Can you show us your current record reader code?

Comment: Thank you for you reply, for example delimiteer maybe some date. Or the ID of the record. In my case the delimiter is date of transactions. For example:   "19.11.2014 11:44  Transaction begin: blabla   19.12.2014 11.22 Transaction failed blabla"